# Google Maps Javascript API working in JS Fiddle but not showing up in localhost

Tags: javascript, html

I'm getting started with Angular and I've been trying to get this map to show up for several hours now, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. There are no errors in the console as far as I can see. Here's my code (which works as expected in JS Fiddle btw):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>    
  </head>
  <body>
  
  <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBIM3O5NdgiqougH2s2vQzHC2_9Mof7Owo&callback=initMap"
      defer></script>
    
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
    console.log("log")  
    let map;
    function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: {
          lat: -34.397,
          lng: 150.644
        },
        zoom: 8
      });
    }
  </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

```
#map {
        height: 500px;
        margin: 0; padding: 0;
      }
      
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

**Things I've tried:**

1. Removing restrictions from the API key
2. Changing the URL from https to http
3. Removing defer attribute
4. Setting the height of #map using px and %
5. Checking if the script tag with the function is executing. (Again,
   the log shows up in JS Fiddle but not in the dev tools console,
   which means that the script is not executing?)

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Copying your code works just fine on my end, the map appears

Comment: Integrating into angular is not as simple as into a basic html page. The element you want it to display in typically doesn't exist when the page loads

Comment: This works in normal HTML. if you are facing this issue in Angular. No need to use call back function. instead you should try using 'ngAfterViewInit' and keep you callback code here.